# How to set custom JsonSerializerSettings for Json.NET in ASP.NET Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I understand that ASP.NET Web API natively uses Json.NET for (de)serializing objects, but is there a way to specify a `JsonSerializerSettings` object that you want for it to use?

For example, what if I wanted to include `type` information into the serialized JSON string? Normally I'd inject settings into the `.Serialize()` call, but Web API does that silently. I can't find a way to inject settings manually.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

You can customize the `JsonSerializerSettings` by using the `Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings` property in the `HttpConfiguration` object.

For example, you could do that in the Application_Start() method:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    HttpConfiguration config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;
    config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Formatting =
        Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;
}
```

Comment: I cant get this to work in ASP.NET app with HangFire installed. It is referencing the incorrect libarary or something. had to use the other answer with Default settings..

Comment: You can do it per controller or action: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44499041/web-api-configure-json-serializer-settings-on-action-or-controller-level

Answer (score 46):

You can specify `JsonSerializerSettings` for each `JsonConvert`, and you can set a global default.

**Single `JsonConvert`** with an overload:

```cs
// Option #1.
JsonSerializerSettings config = new JsonSerializerSettings { ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore };
this.json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(YourObject, Formatting.Indented, config);

// Option #2 (inline).
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(YourObject, Formatting.Indented,
    new JsonSerializerSettings() {
        ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
    }
);
```

**Global Setting** with code in `Application_Start()` in Global.asax.cs:

```cs
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings {
     Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented,
     ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
};
```

Reference: https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/78

Comment: FWIW, the second method was what I initially tried which did *not* work. I had to use `HttpConfiguration` instead as in [carlosfigueira's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13274791/44853) as settings configured in `JsonConvert.DefaultSettings` were not being observed.

Comment: In my case the Global setting usgin `JsonSerializerSettings ` is what worked for me. I could not get the HttpCOnfiguration to work, it was comming back with another assemblies methods (Hangifre) not sure why.

Comment: Can I use hidden field `formHiddenField.Value =  JsonConvert.SerializeObject(listaCursos, Formatting.Indented, jsonSerializerSettings);` and use JQuery for get the value `var data = $('#formHiddenField').val();` ?

Answer (score 1):

Answer is adding this 2 lines of code to Global.asax.cs Application_Start method

```
var json = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = 
    Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.All;
```

Reference: [Handling Circular Object References](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization#handling_circular_object_references)