# Json.Net: Html Helper Method not regenerating

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, json.net

I'm running into a problem where an ASP.NET MVC html helper method I created is not being "regenerated" each time it is called.

The purpose of the helper method is to create Javascript objects to be used in an angularjs framework. For example, here's a code snippet where the helper method is used (called from within a script tag of an html page):

```
var app = angular.module( "appName", ["ui.bootstrap"] );

app.controller( 'appCtrl', function( $scope ) {
    $scope.model = @Html.ToJavascript( Model, new string[] { "FirstName", "LastName", "ID", "Role" } );
} );
```

Model is an instance of a class which has a variety of properties, but I only want FirstName, LastName, ID and Role to get serialized to a javascript object.

The ToJavascript() helper method is defined in a statis class as follows:

```
   public static HtmlString ToJavascript( this HtmlHelper helper, object toConvert, string[] includedFields = null, Formatting formatting = Formatting.Indented, ReferenceLoopHandling loopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore )
    {
        using( var stringWriter = new StringWriter() )
        using( var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter( stringWriter ) )
        {
            var serializer = new JsonSerializer()
            {
                // Let's use camelCasing as is common practice in JavaScript
                ContractResolver = new SpecificFieldsResolver( includedFields ),
                Formatting = formatting,
                ReferenceLoopHandling = loopHandling,
            };

            // We don't want quotes around object names
            jsonWriter.QuoteName = false;
            serializer.Serialize( jsonWriter, toConvert );

            return new HtmlString( stringWriter.ToString() );
        }
    }
```

This utilizes Json.NET to do the actual serialization.

One of the many cool features of Json.NET is that it lets you define, on the fly, which fields get serialized. That's what the SpecificFieldsResolver does. I've defined it as follows:

```
public class SpecificFieldsResolver : CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver
{
    private string[] _included;

    public SpecificFieldsResolver( string[] included )
    {
        _included = included;
    }

    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty( MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization )
    {
        JsonProperty prop = base.CreateProperty( member, memberSerialization );

        bool inclField = ( _included == null )
            || _included.Contains( member.Name, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase );

        prop.ShouldSerialize = obj => inclField;

        return prop;
    }
}
```

What's confusing me is the way that CreateProperty() gets called. Specifically, it seems to only get called once for each type of object being serialized.

That's a problem because in another cshtml file I have another call to ToJavascript() which is attempting to serialize the same type of object, but with different fields to be output from the serialization:

```
var app = angular.module( "app2Name", ["ui.bootstrap"] );

app.controller( 'app2Ctrl', function( $scope ) {
    $scope.model = @Html.ToJavascript( Model, new string[] { "FirstName", "LastName", "ID", "Role", "Category", "VoterID" } );
} );
```

Category and VoterID are also valid class fields. But ToJavascript() doesn't seralize them. Instead, it only serializes the fields defined in the first call to ToJavascript()...even though that call takes place in a different cshtml file. It's as if SpecificFieldsResolver remembers the JsonProperty objects it creates.

Thoughts?

**Update**

Thanx to dbc for diagnosing exactly what was wrong and suggesting a workaround. I adapated it slightly because I rely on Json.NET's camel case name resolution in several resolvers:

```
public class CamelCaseNameMapper : CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver
{
    public string ToCamelCase( string propertyName )
    {
        return ResolvePropertyName( propertyName );
    }
}

public class MaoDefaultContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    private CamelCaseNameMapper _mapper = new CamelCaseNameMapper();

    protected override string ResolvePropertyName( string propertyName )
    {
        return _mapper.ToCamelCase( propertyName );
    }

}
```

Now every resolver, such as my SpecificFieldsResolver, which derives from MaoDefaultContractResolver automatically inherits camel casing but avoids the caching problem the dbc identified.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This appears to be a bug with [`CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver.cs).  Its base class, [`DefaultContractResolver`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver.htm), has two constructors: a [parameterless constructor](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver__ctor.htm), and a [`DefaultContractResolver (Boolean)`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver__ctor_1.htm) version (just made obsolete in Json.NET 7.0).  This parameter has the following meaning:

> shareCache
>
> - Type: System.Boolean
>
>   If set to true the `DefaultContractResolver`will use a cached shared with other resolvers of the same type. Sharing the cache will significantly improve performance with multiple resolver instances because expensive reflection will only happen once. This setting can cause unexpected behavior if different instances of the resolver are suppose to produce different results. When set to false it is highly recommended to reuse `DefaultContractResolver` instances with the `JsonSerializer`.

The default is `false`.

Unfortunately, the [default constructor](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver.cs) for `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver` sets the value to **`true`**:

```
public class CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    public CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
#pragma warning disable 612,618
        : base(true)
#pragma warning restore 612,618
    {
        NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy
        {
            ProcessDictionaryKeys = true,
            OverrideSpecifiedNames = true
        };
    }
}
```

Further, there is no second constructor with the `shareCache` option.  This breaks your `SpecificFieldsResolver`.

As a workaround, you could derive your resolver from `DefaultContractResolver` and use [`CamelCaseNamingStrategy`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_CamelCaseNamingStrategy.htm) to do the name mapping:

```
public class IndependentCamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    public IndependentCamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
        : base()
    {
        NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy
        {
            ProcessDictionaryKeys = true,
            OverrideSpecifiedNames = true
        };
    }    
}

public class SpecificFieldsResolver : IndependentCamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver
{
    // Remainder unchanged
}
```

Note that if you are using a version of Json.NET prior to 9.0, `CamelCaseNamingStrategy` does not exist.  Instead a kludge nested `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver` can be used to map the names:

```
public class IndependentCamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    class CamelCaseNameMapper : CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver
    {
        // Purely to make the protected method public.
        public string ToCamelCase(string propertyName)
        {
            return ResolvePropertyName(propertyName);
        }
    }
    readonly CamelCaseNameMapper nameMapper = new CamelCaseNameMapper();

    protected override string ResolvePropertyName(string propertyName)
    {
        return nameMapper.ToCamelCase(propertyName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow! And here I thought my question was too obscure, and too undocumented, to generate an answer. Thank you very much! Your analysis was exactly correct. I took a slightly different approach to your solution simply because I was using the camel case resolution capability in several resolvers. Do you know if this limitation was reported to Json.NET?

Comment: @MarkOlbert - Glad to help.  no, I don't know if it has been reported.

Comment: Thank you so much for this explanation. Was driving me batty.

Comment: Ran into the same issue here, only took most of a day to figure out the problem, and only an hour to figure out the CamelCase constructor issue. At least we have the source to read.