# Json.NET: How to make DefaultValueHandling only apply to certain types?

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, json.net

I have a custom class that looks like this:

```
public class PartnerLoginOptions
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string DeviceModel { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }

    public bool? IncludeUrls { get; set; }
    public bool? ReturnDeviceType { get; set; }
    public bool? ReturnUpdatePromptVersions { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like to ignore any `bool?` members with default values when serializing, but keep strings with null values. For example, if I had an object like this

```
var options = new PartnerLoginOptions
{
    Username = null,
    Password = "123",
    IncludeUrls = null,
    ReturnDeviceType = true
};
```

Then serializing would result in this:

```
{
    "username": null,
    "password": "123",
    "deviceModel": null,
    "version": null,
    "returnDeviceType": true
}
```

Here is the code I have so far:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
    DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore // this applies to strings too, not just bool?
};

return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(options, settings);
```

Is there any way to do this without individually tagging each `OptionalBool` property with `[JsonProperty(DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore)]`? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a [custom contract resolver](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/contractresolver.htm) inheriting from [`DefaultContractResolver`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver.htm) that applies `DefaultValueHandling.Ignore` to all properties of your required types.  However, your specific question has some constraints:

1. You want to apply a default value handling to a *system type*, namely `bool?`.  Thus the contract resolver cannot be implemented by applying some custom attribute to the type, then checking for it in [`CreateProperty()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver_CreateProperty.htm).  Instead it will be necessary to pass a collection of overrides to the contract resolver's constructor.
2. You are using [`CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver.htm).  If you subclass it and pass different lists of overrides to different instances, you will encounter the bug from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30740734/json-net-html-helper-method-not-regenerating) that contracts are forcibly shared across all instances of each subtype, even if different instances would otherwise return different contracts.  Thus it will be necessary to inherit from `DefaultContractResolver`, which does not have this bug, and set [`DefaultContractResolver.NamingStrategy`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver_NamingStrategy.htm) to a [`CamelCaseNamingStrategy`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_CamelCaseNamingStrategy.htm).

Therefore your contract resolver should look like:

```
public class DefaultValueContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    readonly Dictionary<Type, DefaultValueHandling> overrides;

    public DefaultValueContractResolver(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<Type, DefaultValueHandling>> overrides) : base()
    {
        if (overrides == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("overrides");
        this.overrides = overrides.ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value);
    }

    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
        if (property.DefaultValueHandling == null)
        {
            DefaultValueHandling handling;
            if (overrides.TryGetValue(property.PropertyType, out handling))
                property.DefaultValueHandling = handling;
        }

        return property;
    }
}
```

Then use it like:

```
var options = new PartnerLoginOptions
{
    Username = null,
    Password = "123",
    IncludeUrls = null,
    ReturnDeviceType = true
};

var resolver = new DefaultValueContractResolver(
    new Dictionary<Type, DefaultValueHandling>
    { 
        { typeof(bool?), DefaultValueHandling.Ignore } 
    })
    {
        NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy()
    };
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = resolver };
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(options, Formatting.Indented, settings);
```

Notes:

- If you have a standard list of types for which you always apply a default value handling override, you should [cache an instance of the contract resolver](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Performance.htm#ReuseContractResolver) for best performance.
- Contract resolver naming strategies were introduced in Json.NET [9.0.1](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases/tag/9.0.1).  If you are using an earlier version and need camel casing, you will need to subclass `DefaultValueContractResolver` and add it yourself, e.g. as follows:

  ```cs
  public class DefaultValueCamelCaseContractResolver : DefaultValueContractResolver
  {
      public DefaultValueCamelCaseContractResolver(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<Type, DefaultValueHandling>> overrides) : base(overrides) { }

      protected override string ResolvePropertyName(string propertyName)
      {
          return propertyName.ToCamelCase();
      }
  }

  public static class CamelCaseNameExtensions
  {
      class CamelCaseNameResolver : CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver
      {
          // Explicit static constructor to tell C# compiler not to mark type as beforefieldinit
          static CamelCaseNameResolver() { }
          internal static readonly CamelCaseNameResolver Instance = new CamelCaseNameResolver();

          // Purely to make the protected method public.
          public string ToCamelCase(string propertyName)
          {
              return ResolvePropertyName(propertyName);
          }
      }

      public static string ToCamelCase(this string propertyName)
      {
          if (propertyName == null)
              return null;
          return CamelCaseNameResolver.Instance.ToCamelCase(propertyName);
      }
  }
  ```

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Om1O6p).