# Ignoring some default values for serialization

Tags: json.net, protocol-buffers

tl;dr; In Newtonsoft JSON.NET, how do you ignore default values for some types (enums), and not others (ints)?

---

My team is consuming a library that uses protocol buffers for their business entities. Every enumeration in this library/protobuf has a default value of 0, "ValueNotSet". My team is using Newtonsoft JSON.NET to serialize these entities. Here's a diluted example for a bakery's inventory:

```
public enum Flavor { ValueNotSet, Cherry, Blueberry, Cheese };
public class DanishInventory { public int QtyInStock; public Flavor; }
```

In order to conserve resources we do not want to serialize `ValueNotSet` (the real world scenario has many enumerations), but having zero cheese danishes in stock is valid and we **do** want to serialize zero. Because of this, we cannot use DefaultValueHandling = Ignore in settings.

I created a custom JsonConverter, but by the time WriteJson(...) is called the key is already in the JsonWriter. So if I write nothing the JSON is invalid, and I don't see an obvious method to back-track the writer to overwrite a key. So what is the best way to ignore default values for some types (e.g. enums), but not others (e.g. ints)?

Note that the enums are in a NuGet package and cannot be modified, e.g. by adding attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a variation of the `DefaultValueContractResolver` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38001656/3744182) to *[Json.NET: How to make DefaultValueHandling only apply to certain types?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37995738/3744182)* to exclude all enum-valued properties with default values:

```
public class EnumDefaultValueContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
        if (property.DefaultValueHandling == null)
        {
            if (property.PropertyType.IsEnum)
            {
                //For safety you could check here if the default value is named ValueNotSet and only set IgnoreAndPopulate in that case.
                //var defaultValue = Enum.ToObject(property.PropertyType, 0);
                //if (defaultValue.ToString() == "ValueNotSet")
                //{                 
                    property.DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.IgnoreAndPopulate; // Or DefaultValueHandling.Ignore if you prefer
                //}
            }
        }

        return property;
    }
}
```

Then use it as follows:

```
var resolver = new EnumDefaultValueContractResolver();

var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = resolver };
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(inventory, settings);
```

You may want to [cache the contract resolver for best performance](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Performance.htm#ReuseContractResolver).

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qTmi43).

Answer (score 1):

Many serializers, (including Json.NET I believe) support the `ShouldSerialize*()` pattern; if you don't mind doing this on a per-usage basis, you could do:

```cs
public class DanishInventory {
    public int QtyInStock;
    public Flavor;
    public bool ShouldSerializeFlavor() => Flavor != 0;
}
```