# Reset Json.NET Contract-Cache

Tags: c#, json, caching, json.net

I am using a custom Json.NET contract resolver in my project which adds some more properties to the contract model.

```cs
protected override JsonObjectContract CreateObjectContract(Type objectType)
{
    var contract = base.CreateObjectContract(objectType);
    AddSomeMorePropertiesToContract(contract, objectType);

    return contract;
}
```

During the lifetime of the application this custom property-list of my models can change, some of the properties might be removed and some might be added.

However Json.NET resolves the `JsonObjectContracts` and its properties only *once* when the type is used for the first time and caches it, so the the new properties-list is never applied!

**Is there a way to tell Json.NET that it should reset its cache and resolve the contracts again?**

---

The only workaround I found to achieve this is to store all contracts after they have been created and manually manipulate their properties when I want to update them:

```cs
public class MyContractResolver : CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver
{
    private static List<JsonObjectContract> OldContracts { get; } = new List<JsonObjectContract>();

    protected override JsonContract CreateContract(Type type)
    {
        var contract = base.CreateContract(type);
        OldContracts.Add((JsonObjectContract)contract);

        return contract;
    }

    public void UpdateContracts()
    {
        foreach (var oldContract in OldContracts)
        {
            oldContract.Properties.Clear();
            var newContract = (JsonObjectContract)base.CreateContract(oldContract.UnderlyingType);
            oldContract.Properties.AddRange(newContract.Properties);
        }
    }
```

This works, but instead of manually updating the properties, I would much prefere to only somehow reset the cache and let Json.NET resolve the contracts again on its own.

Comment: Why not just discard the old `ContractResolver` and construct a new one?

Comment: ... Oh, I see the problem.  You're using `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver` which shares contract information across all instances of each subtype.  Instead, inherit from `DefaultContractResolver` and set `NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy()` as is shown in [Json.Net: Html Helper Method not regenerating](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30743234/3744182).  Then you will be able to refresh your contract information by simply constructing a new contract resolver.  (In fact this may be a duplicate.  Agree?)

Comment: @dbc you are right, creating my own ContractResolver with the CamelCaseNamingStrategy and constructing a new resolver-instance when something has changed solved it! If you add this as an answere I will mark it as solution. Yes, you could consider this as a borderline duplicate of the question you mentioned. Thx heaps!