# How can I serialise PSObjects in C# with JSON.NET?

Tags: c#, powershell, json.net

I am writing a Cmdlet and need to pass object structures into an API client that may contain `PSObject`s. Currently, these serialise as a JSON string containing CLIXML. Instead, I need it to be treated like an object (including the NoteProperties in `PSObject.Properties` as properties, and recursively serialising their values).

I tried writing my own `JsonConverter` but for some reason it only gets called for the top level object, not for nested `PSObject`s:

```
public class PSObjectJsonConverter : JsonConverter {

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer) {
        if (value is PSObject) {
            JObject obj = new JObject();
            foreach (var prop in ((PSObject)value).Properties) {
                obj.Add(new JProperty(prop.Name, value));
            }
            obj.WriteTo(writer);
        } else {
            JToken token = JToken.FromObject(value);
            token.WriteTo(writer);
        }
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool CanRead {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Additionally, I am using serializing to camel case using `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver`.  Is there a way to make the converter respect that?

Comment: With C#7 you can simplify with `if(value is PSObject pso)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following converter should correctly serialize recursively nested objects of type [`PSObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psobject?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0):

```
public class PSObjectJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(PSObject).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var psObj = (PSObject)value;
        writer.WriteStartObject();
        foreach (var prop in psObj.Properties)
        {
            //Probably we shouldn't try to serialize a property that can't be read.
            //https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.pspropertyinfo.isgettable?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0#System_Management_Automation_PSPropertyInfo_IsGettable
            if (!prop.IsGettable)
                continue;           
            writer.WritePropertyName(prop.Name);
            serializer.Serialize(writer, prop.Value);
        }
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool CanRead { get { return false; } }
}
```

Notes:

- In [`WriteJson`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter_WriteJson.htm) you serialize the incoming object `value` as the value of each property.  Surely you meant [`prop.Value`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psproperty.value?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0#System_Management_Automation_PSProperty_Value).
- By only returning `true` from [`CanConvert()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter_CanConvert.htm) when the incoming object type is of type `PSObject`, you avoid the need to implement default serialization for non-`PSObject` types in `WriteJson()`.
- When you call `JToken.FromObject(value)` you are not using the incoming `JsonSerializer serializer`.  Thus, any `JsonSerializerSettings` (including converters) will be lost.  In theory you could use [`JToken.FromObject(Object, JsonSerializer)`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_FromObject_1.htm) instead, which would preserve settings, but if you did, you would encounter the bug described in *[JSON.Net throws StackOverflowException when using [JsonConvert()]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29719509/3744182)*.  Luckily, since we now return `false` from `CanConvert` when default serialization is required, this is no longer necessary.
- There is no need to construct an intermediate `JObject`.  You can write directly to the `JsonWriter`, which will be somewhat more performant.

**Update**: *Additionally, I am using serializing to camel case using `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver`.  Is there a way to make the converter respect that?*

Once you introduce a [custom `JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) for your type, you need to do everything manually, including remapping of property names.  Here's a version of `WriteJson()` that handles this by using [`DefaultContractResolver.NamingStrategy`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver_NamingStrategy.htm):

```
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var psObj = (PSObject)value;
        writer.WriteStartObject();
        var resolver = serializer.ContractResolver as DefaultContractResolver;
        var strategy = (resolver == null ? null : resolver.NamingStrategy) ?? new DefaultNamingStrategy();

        foreach (var prop in psObj.Properties)
        {
            //Probably we shouldn't try to serialize a property that can't be read.
            //https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.pspropertyinfo.isgettable?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0#System_Management_Automation_PSPropertyInfo_IsGettable
            if (!prop.IsGettable)
                continue;
            writer.WritePropertyName(strategy.GetPropertyName(prop.Name, false));
            serializer.Serialize(writer, prop.Value);
        }
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }
```

Note that naming strategies were introduced in [Json.NET 9.0.1](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases/tag/9.0.1) so if you are using an earlier version you will need to create your own camel case name mapper such as the one shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30743234/3744182).

Comment: Note - tried to test here but failed due to `SecurityException` exceptions: https://dotnetfiddle.net/AJokws

Comment: Thank you so much, that works indeed! Except one thing, it doesn't seem to respect `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver` for the property keys. Is there a way to make it respect that?

Comment: Very great answer! It absolutely helps.