# How to make JSON output key with Pascal Case for a single action method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json.net, .net-4.6.1

I am trying to make JSON output returned from a single controller action (don't want to set it global) as like this (PascalCase) :

```
{
    "AuthenticationResult": {
        "AccessToken": "",
        "ExpiresIn": 0,
        "TokenType": "",
        "RefreshToken": "",
        "IdToken": ""
    }
}
```

**DTO Class:**

```
public class AuthResponse
{
    public AuthenticationResult authenticationResult { get; set; }
}

public class AuthenticationResult
{
    [JsonProperty("AccessToken")]
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }
    public int ExpiresIn { get; set; }
    public string TokenType { get; set; }
    public string RefreshToken { get; set; }
    public string IdToken { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller Method:**

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetAuthenticationToken(string Guid = null)
{
    try
    {
        var AuthResponse = await _Business.GetAuthenticationTokenAsync(Guid, null);

        return Ok(AuthResponse, this);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return BadRequest(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

The DTOs `AuthResponse` and `AuthenticationResult` are not used elsewhere.

Comment: 1) What version of asp.net are you using?  2) `[JsonProperty("AccessToken")]` is from Json.NET not System.Text.Json, are you certain you are using Json.NET? 3)  If using Json.NET, how are your `JsonSerializerSettings` configured?  4) Are your DTOs `AuthResponse` and `AuthenticationResult` used elsewhere, or can they be modifier to force a pascal case return?

Comment: .Net Framework 4.6.1

Comment: Then definitely Json.NET.  Can you modify your DTOs to add attributes?

Comment: and, AuthResponse/AuthenticationResult is not used elsewhere

Comment: Tried to modify using JsonProperty, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify your DTOs to add [`[JsonObject(NamingStrategyType = typeof(DefaultNamingStrategy))]`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonContainerAttribute_NamingStrategyType.htm):

```
[JsonObject(NamingStrategyType = typeof(DefaultNamingStrategy))]
public class AuthResponse
{
    [JsonProperty("AuthenticationResult")]
    public AuthenticationResult authenticationResult { get; set; }
}

[JsonObject(NamingStrategyType = typeof(DefaultNamingStrategy))]
public class AuthenticationResult
{
    [JsonProperty("AccessToken")]
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }
    public int ExpiresIn { get; set; }
    public string TokenType { get; set; }
    public string RefreshToken { get; set; }
    public string IdToken { get; set; }
}
```

You need to do this because, if you are using [`CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_serialization_camelcasepropertynamescontractresolver.htm), it will even camel-case property names specified via [`JsonPropertyAttribute.PropertyName`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute_PropertyName.htm).  Applying a naming strategy to the object itself prevents this behavior.

Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GsjeIA).

Alternatively, you could modify your global settings and use a contract resolver that does not override specified names by setting [`NamingStrategy.OverrideSpecifiedNames = false`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_NamingStrategy_OverrideSpecifiedNames.htm): <sup>[1]</sup>

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
settings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver { 
    NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy { 
        OverrideSpecifiedNames = false // Prevent modification of property names set by [JsonProperty("name")]
    } 
};
```

And then your `[JsonProperty("AuthenticationResult")]` will not get camel-cased.  However, since you only want to pascal-case a single action method, this is probably not the preferred solution.

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uc5oLe).

---

<sup>[1]</sup> Do **not** modify the naming strategy of `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver`, create an instance of `DefaultContractResolver` instead.  `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver` shares contracts across all instances of its type, so modifying one instance will change its behavior across your application.  For details see e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30743234/3744182) to *[Json.Net: Html Helper Method not regenerating](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30740734/3744182)*.