# What does Mandrill status = "invalid" mean in Send Message API response

Tags: api, response, status, mandrill, sendmessage

Mandrill official documentation says that the `status` property in the response of `Send Message` API request is:

> the sending status of the recipient - either "sent", "queued", "scheduled", "rejected", or "invalid"

Can't find anywhere what does `invalid` status indicate.

Any idea, referece ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One reason I have found is an invalid email address. For example having two dots in a domain like this: *alice@example..com*

Comment: So, we know at least one reason for that status, but unfortunately we can't be sure that it is the only reason. It's strange that such an important thing is not documented by Mandrill.

Comment: From what I can see Mandrill is essentially an abandoned product: client libraries are no longer supported, basic features like rendering a text template have been promised for years but never delivered, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen because some of the properties in the JSON I posted had uppercase letters when the mandrill api was expecting lowercase.

I was using newtonsoft and solved it by adding JsonProperty attributes to my objects as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34071205