# .Net Core 3.0: Apply AddJsonOptions only to a specifc controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I have two controller `FooController` and `BooController` (the last is for a backward compatibility), I want only the `FooController` will return its model with upper camel case notation ("UpperCamelCase").

For example:

```
public class MyData 
{
    public string Key {get;set;}
    public string Value {get;set;} 
}

public class BooController : ControllerBase 
{
    public ActionResult<MyData> GetData() { ... } 
} 
public class FooController : ControllerBase 
{
    public ActionResult<MyData> GetData() { ... } 
}
```

The desired `GET` output:

```
GET {{domain}}/api/Boo/getData 
[
    {
        "key": 1,
        "value": "val"
    } 
]

GET {{domain}}/api/Foo/getData 
[
    {
        "Key": 1,
        "Value": "val"
    } 
]
```

If I'm using the `AddJsonOptions` extension with `option.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null` like:

```
services.AddMvc()
.AddJsonOptions(option =>
{
    option.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
});
```

both `BooController` and `FooController` returns the data with upper camel case notation.

**How to make only the `FooController` to return the data in upper camel case notation format?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `[JsonProperty("name")]` in the response class property.

[stackoverflow.com/a/34071205/5952008](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34071205/5952008)

Answer (score 0):

Solved (although kind of bad performance and a hacky solution - hoping for someone to suggest a better solution):

Inside the legacy `BooController` I'm serializing the response just before returning it using a custom formater of `JsonSerializerSettings`:

```
public class BooController : ControllerBase 
{
    public ActionResult<MyData> GetData() 
    {
        var formatter = JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
            ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
        };
        return Ok(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response, Formatting.Indented, formatter()));
    } 
}
```

Result in:

```
GET {{domain}}/api/Boo/getData 
[
    {
        "key": 1,
        "value": "val"
    } 
]
```

Comment: You can just return `JsonResult`. return `new JsonResult(response, jsonSerializerSettings)`. Or even you can create method which will take object and ContractResolvers and will create json result.