# Data retrieved from cache is returned, but is not shown on the page

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, react-redux, asp.net-core-webapi, memorycache

I am using a ASP.NET Core Web API. Here with a middleware, if the response of the incoming request is available in the cache, I send it back in the response.

I can retrieve all the data and view it on the page in requests I make without using the cache.

However, when I use the cache, I still retrieve the data, but when I try to view it, the data is undefined and I cannot be shown.

I don't understand what is causing this problem.

**Request**

```
export function getCategories() {
return async function (dispatch, getState) {
    await axios.get(CATEGORIES_PATH).then((res) => {
        dispatch(getCategoriesSuccess(res.data))
        console.log("categories:",res.data);
        return res.data;
    }).catch(err => redirectErrPage(err, dispatch));
}}
```

**React**

```
class CategoryList extends Component {

componentDidMount() {
    this.props.actions.getCategories();
}
render() {
    return (
        <div >
            <ListGroup className="shadow-lg">
                <ListGroupItem >
                    <h5>
                        {
                            this.props.categories.map(c => (
                                <Link key={c.id} to={"/feed/" + encodeURIComponent(c.name)} className="text-decoration-none"> <Badge
                                    variant="info"
                                    className="ml-2 mt-2 cursorPointer category "
                                >{c.name}</Badge></Link>
                            ))
                        }
                    </h5>
                </ListGroupItem>
            </ListGroup>
        </div>
    )
}}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return { categories: state.categoryListReducer, selectedCategories: state.selectedCategoriesReducer }
}
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        actions: {
            getCategories: bindActionCreators(categoryAsyncActions.getCategories, dispatch)
        }
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CategoryList);
```

### **Without cache**

**Redux**

[image][image]

### **With cache**

**Redux**

[image][image]

Comment: For whatever reason you have an uppercase property `Id` in your cached version rather than the lowercase `id`.  I believe finding the reason for the uppercase `Id` and fixing it at it's source should fix this.

Comment: Yes that is very true. How could I not see that. I solved this with the `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver` class. Thank you so much.               
see [Newtonsoft JsonSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34070459/newtonsoft-jsonserializer-lower-case-properties-and-dictionary)