# Newtonsoft JsonConvert.SerializeObject ignoring JsonProperty if name is uppercase

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, json.net

I want to be able to use the `CamelCasePropertyNameContractResolver` but override it for specific property names. For this, I use the `JsonProperty` attribute. This works fine except when the name that I choose is fully uppercase. Any ideas what's wrong or how to get around it?

In the example below, `Bar` is serialized to `"BAR"` when I don't use the CamelCasePropertyNameContractResolver, but is serialized to `"bar"` when I do use the resolver. `Foo` and `CamelCaseProperty` are serialized correctly in both scenarios.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleTester
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var foo = new FooBar {CamelCaseProperty = "test", Foo = "test", Bar = "test" };
            var output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo);
            // output "CamelCaseProperty", "fOO", "BAR"

            var output2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo, new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() });
            // output "camelCaseProperty", "fOO", "bar"
        }
    }

    public class FooBar
    {
        public string CamelCaseProperty { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("fOO")]
        public string Foo { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("BAR")]
        public string Bar { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Rather than `new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()` use `new DefaultContractResolver { NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy() }`.  For why, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40732416/3744182).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**The reason** you are seeing this is that `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver` is intentionally designed to override the casing of [dictionary keys](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_NamingStrategy_ProcessDictionaryKeys.htm) and [explicitly set property names](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_NamingStrategy_OverrideSpecifiedNames.htm), as can be see from the [reference source](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver.cs#L77):

```
public CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
{
    NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy
    {
        ProcessDictionaryKeys = true,
        OverrideSpecifiedNames = true
    };
}
```

If you don't want that, you have several options to prevent casing of explicit names without creating your own custom contract resolver type.

**Firstly**, you could serialize using a [`DefaultContractResolver`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver.htm) with [`NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver_NamingStrategy.htm):

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings 
{ 
    ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver { NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy() }
};
var output2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo, settings);
```

This leaves [`CamelCaseNamingStrategy.OverrideSpecifiedNames`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_CamelCaseNamingStrategy.htm) at its default value of `false`.

**Secondly**, if you don't have access to the contract resolver of your framework, you could set [`JsonPropertyAttribute.NamingStrategyType = typeof(DefaultNamingStrategy)`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute_NamingStrategyType.htm) on specific properties, like so:

```
public class FooBar
{
    public string CamelCaseProperty { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("fOO")]
    public string Foo { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("BAR", NamingStrategyType = typeof(DefaultNamingStrategy))]
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

**Thirdly**, if you want your *entire object* to ignore the naming strategy of the current contract resolver, you can apply [`[JsonObject(NamingStrategyType = typeof(TNamingStrategy))]`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonContainerAttribute_NamingStrategyType.htm) to your object:

```
[JsonObject(NamingStrategyType = typeof(CamelCaseNamingStrategy))]
public class FooBar
{
    public string CamelCaseProperty { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("fOO")]
    public string Foo { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("BAR")]
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

Notes:

- While it is also possible to modify the `NamingStrategy` of an instance of [`CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver.cs#L68), since the latter [shares contract information globally across all instances of each type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30743234/3744182), this can lead to unexpected side-effects if your application tries to use multiple instances of `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver`.  No such problem exists with `DefaultContractResolver`, so it is safer to use when any customization of casing logic is required.
- When using or subclassing `DefaultContractResolver`, you may want to [cache the contract resolver](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33557737/3744182) for best performance, since it does not share contract information globally across all instances of each type.
- I don't know why Json.NET's camel case resolver is designed to override specified names, it may be for historical reasons.
- Naming strategies were first introduced in [Json.NET 9.0.1](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases/tag/9.0.1) so this answer works only for that version and later.

Comment: In my case second variand works best. I need to keep whole objects serialization in camel case and only few properties in PascalCase.

Answer (score 0):

JsonProperty Attribute is not honoured when you use a ContractResolver.

What you can do to solve this issue is override the ContractResolver:

```
public class MyResolver : CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
        if(member.GetCustomAttribute<JsonPropertyAttribute>() is JsonPropertyAttribute jsonProperty)
        {
            property.PropertyName = jsonProperty.PropertyName;
        }

        return property;
    }
}
```

And use your Resolver:

```
var output2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo, new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new MyResolver() });
```

Comment: To some extend the JsonProperty attribute has to be honoured. Otherwise, why would the property Foo be serialized as fOO instead of foo?

Comment: Yes, your are right. But it honor JsonProperty before use ContractResolver. So fOO is camelCame fOO, but BAR is camelCase bar.