# JSON.NET conditionally change the naming strategy to camel case for specific properties only

Tags: json.net

Suppose a class Foo with 2 properties, PropertyA and PropertyB.

With JSON.NET i would like to use the **DefaultContractResolver** for serializing *PropertyA* and the **CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver** for serializing *PropertyB*.

So that the resultant serialized class would look like this.

Foo.**PropertyA**

Foo.**propertyB**

Is there a way to do this with JSON.NET?

Extra credit, i would prefer to denote which properties to serialize using the **CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver** by using an attibute.

Comment: You don't need to use a different contract resolver, you need to use a different [naming strategy](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/NamingStrategySkipSpecifiedNames.htm).  E.g. see [Newtonsoft JsonConvert.SerializeObject ignoring JsonProperty if name is uppercase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48652197/3744182), [Configure Json.NET serialization settings on a class level](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44805490/3744182) or [How to apply a general rule for remapping all property names when serializing with Json.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46477576/3744182).

Comment: Do those linked questions also answer your question, or do you need additional help?  If so can you please [edit] your question to share a [mcve] showing what your current classes with desired output JSON?