# NewtonSoft.Json usign camelCase when it shouldnt - machine dependent?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, json.net

## Serializing problem

It seems like NewtonSoft.Json outputs different Json based on the machine. But only for a single property

The difference and curios thing is that any **key** in `Settings` gets converted to a camelCase. But any **key** in `ExtraFields` remains the same casing it was

## Demonstration

[image: Correct output on left, wrong output on right]

## Code

.net 7

My model, saved in a database as a jsonb column (postgress)

```
 public class VersionData
 {    
     [JsonProperty("settings")]
     public IDictionary<string, JToken>? Settings { get; set; }

     [JsonExtensionData]
     public IDictionary<string, JToken> ExtraFields = new Dictionary<string, JToken>();
 }
```

My database model builder is as follows

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyModel>(x =>

  x.Property(p => p.VersionData).IsRequired().HasColumnType("jsonb")
      .HasConversion(v => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(v), v =>    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<VersionData>(v));
```

My API init setup

```
services.AddControllers()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(opt =>
    {
        opt.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
        {
            NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy()
            {
                ProcessDictionaryKeys = false//this is the default anyway, but explicitly set
            }
        };
        opt.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());
    });
```

## Expected result

Just based on all the above, i would expect that the keys should not be modified, and have their casign preserved. This is indeed what i see on my machine, and on a deployed version of the code.

However when running on k8s pod, it appears to change the expected behaviour.

I dont think this has anything to do with k8's or any reverseproxy, as the  `ExtraFields` dictionary keeps the correct casing

I made sure the running code is 100% identical. Tried adding additional properties such as the one included in the image  `myExtraUnmapped` and this preserved the casing.

But the different behaviour per deployed environemnt has me stummped. No idea what else it could be

Comment: Never modify any properties of `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver`, it shares contract globally across all instances.  So the contract returned by one instance may be affected by the properties of another instance, here `NamingStrategy`.  If you need to modify your contract resolver's properties in any way, use `DefaultContractResolver`.

Comment: For confirmation, see the last note in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40732416/3744182) to [Keep casing when serializing dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24143149/3744182) as well as [Json.Net: Html Helper Method not regenerating](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30743234/3744182).

Comment: Another possibility is that, on the machine where serialization is behaving incorrectly, somewhere [`JsonConvert.DefaultSettings`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DefaultSettings.htm) has been set up.  You can check that easily enough by asserting the return is null.

Comment: I will look more into the links you posted, however what is strange to me, is that the `ExtraFields` preserve the casing, but the `Settings` does not. So whilst i should follow your advise above. It doest seem like its the cause of the issues above. As both results would be affected

Comment: Not necessarily, since `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver` caches and reuses contracts **globally**, the decision to camel case a given type will (I believe) be determined on the first call to `ResolveContract()` in any given app domain for that specific type.  So if you are using multiple `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver` with different naming strategies the behavior will depend on the order in which calls are made going all the way back to process / app domain startup.

Comment: Ok thanks. I will look into this a bit further and see what i find