# Post Method in Angular - Part Model

Tags: c#, angularjs, ionic-framework, asp.net-web-api2

I have a rather unusual issue I've encountered.

We are currently developing an Ionic application - using Web API as back-end DB. Within the application, we call a $http.post method to post data back to the API, which looks like the following:

```
$http.post(
    ApiEndpoint.url + '/PostUpdate/',
    JSON.stringify(postData),
    {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    }
).success(function(data) {
    alert("WORKS!");
});
```

I can see all the data being POST-ed successfully via the Google Chrome Developer Tools:

[image]

However when the POST hits the Web API - not all of the data is featured in the model. Using the above data as an example, you can see that the element "DetailsOfConversation" has data in it - however it is set to null in the model:

[image]

however other properties (e.g. OutcomeId, TimeAttend, attendGivenAddress, jobId) have correct values set. This one has me stumped! Any ideas of where I can start hunting the problem down?

EDIT: I've implemented the following custom attribute:
http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Dec/13/Accepting-Raw-Request-Body-Content-with-ASPNET-Web-API

to allow me to view the raw body of the POST data, it seems the missing fields ARE there:

[image]

so i guess if this can't be solved, I'll simply extract the data from that (not ideal, I know)

Comment: What's data type of DetailsOfConversation?! If it's not a string then you are passing a string so that property won't be serialized.

Comment: Hey there it's definitely a string

Comment: Try it without the JSON.stringify and pass the postData directly just to see if that works. You shouldn't have to stringify the data.

Comment: Thanks @Lex - tried that without luck - got exactly the same result :(

Comment: This should be working and it bugged me enough that I built a little app and ran it locally to test it. Everything worked fine, the data was POSTed to my WebApi controller method just fine - all the data was present. I tried both with and without JSON.stringify() and that didn't make a difference. I should note that I did not specifically set the content type, but when I inspected it it shows as `application/json;charset=utf-8`.

Comment: Thanks @Lex - appreciate your efforts - it SHOULD work - I agree! I've had similar weird issues previously with web API - eventually I've worked them out! This one has me stumped

Answer (score 0):

Please check your serializer and make sure that you have received content type `'application\json', probably you dont have registered json serialiser or content type accepted as`'x-www-form-urlencoded'`. I had similar problem before and its source were in serializer.

Comment: I've set the JSON serialiser using the following in my Global.asax.cs:

HttpConfiguration config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;

take from:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13274625/how-to-set-custom-jsonserializersettings-for-json-net-in-mvc-4-web-api

and I'm also setting:

'Content-Type': 'application/json'

in my $http.post

Answer (score 0):

I've got a deadline to meet - so I've had to put a work-around in:

```
dynamic json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(input);
string conversation = json.DetailsOfConversation;
```

The above gives me the data I need, not ideal but I guess a workaround.