# How can I serialize a c# integer as a JSON string without changing the c# data type?

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

I have the following customer class in c#:

```
class Customer 
{
  public int CustomerID;
  public string Name;
}
```

I am trying to convert the class object to Json string using Newtonsoft.Json:

```
Customer c = new Customer();
c.CustomerID = 1;
c.Name = "Test";
string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
```

It generates:

```
{"CustomerID": 1, "Name": "Test"}
```

Is it possible to wrap Customer ID to double quotes (without changing CustomerID data type from int to string)?

```
{"CustomerID": "1", "Name": "Test"}
```

Comment: question: **why** would you want this? and why isn't turning it into a string an option?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41783225/json-deserialization-string-is-automatically-converted-to-int also this one

Comment: @Izikon I think that's backwards

Comment: as a resourceful software engineer you are , you can reverse it

Comment: @Franz Gleichmann - I have to pass the JSON to another system which requires it in double quotes.

Comment: Thanks @Izikon, I managed to get it working with your solution