# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject not automatically deserialising string to int

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I'm trying to de-serialize the `{"fileNumber": "1"}` JSON into the following object.

```
CustmObj jFile = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustmObj>(json)objects.

public class CustmObj
{
   [JsonProperty("fileNumber")]
   public uint FileNumber { get; set; }
}
```

I'm expecting it to automatically convert the int to string, however it keeps throwing the error `"Error converting value .. to type 'System.UInt32'. Path ..."`

How can I do this?

Comment: That's how it is supposed to work.

Comment: Is there a work-around for it? So that I'd be able to convert the string to int?

Comment: @AluanHaddad is correct, this is intended functionality of Json.NET.  It automatically deserializes string-valued properties like `"1"` when the declared C# type is numeric.  If you don't like that you can add a custom converter for `uint` like the one for `int` from [JSON Deserialization - String Is Automatically Converted To Int](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41783225).  Does that question also answer yours?

Comment: You could specify a private string and mark that as the deserialization target and then use accessors to convert in your public property. But there are many ways.

Comment: Oh wait. are you saying that Json.NET will automatically convert `"1"` to an `int` but will not do so for a `uint`?  And you are asking how to get the same behavior for `uint`?  ... No, I can't reproduce that, `int` and `uint` behave identically.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/0cKL9F

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JSON Deserialization - String Is Automatically Converted To Int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41783225/json-deserialization-string-is-automatically-converted-to-int)

Comment: @dbc and Heretic Monkey, I saw that question but I was hoping that there was a simple solution like an Attribute was available, looks like I was wrong

Comment: I'm a little confused how you are getting the error *`Error converting value .. to type 'System.UInt32'. Path ...`*  Can you share a [mcve]?  As it is your JSON deserializes successfully, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/0cKL9F.  Or is your problem that you want to get an error instead of a successful deserialization?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to de-serialize the {"fileNumber": "1"} json into the
> following object.

Just remove the " of integer : {"fileNumber": 1}

Comment: Unfortunately I can't, the string is only a part of a larger file which is not generated by myself.

Comment: so, follow the link post above : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41783225/json-deserialization-string-is-automatically-converted-to-int