# Json.Net deserialize into C# derived class

Tags: c#, json, serialization, asp.net-web-api, json.net

Json.Net is *not* deserializing the object it receives into the proper derivatives of my Control class. (Please see the following explanation of the problem. Also please note, I feel this is the minimum amount of code required to explain the issue. Thanks ahead of time for reviewing this problem.)

I am trying to serialize/deserialize the following class(es) into/from JSON.

```
public class Page {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }
    public IList<Control> Controls { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the Control class:

```
public class Control : ControlBase
{
    public override Enums.CsControlType CsControlType { get { return Enums.CsControlType.Base; } }
}
```

And here is the ControlBase abstract class:

```
public abstract class ControlBase
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Enums.CsControlType CsControlType { get; }

    public Enums.ControlType Type { get; set; }

    public string PropertyName { get; set; }

    public IList<int> Width { get; set; }

    public string FriendlyName { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the OptionsControl which is derived from Control:

```
public class OptionsControl : Control
{
    public override Enums.CsControlType CsControlType { get { return Enums.CsControlType.OptionsControl; } }

    public IDictionary<string, string> Options;
}
```

When the OptionsControl is serialized, the JSON looks like the following. Note that Json.Net adds the `$type` property, so that (supposedly) it can deserialize the control back into an OptionsControl.

```
              {  
                 "options":{  
                    "TN":"TN"
                 },
                 "csControlType":4,
                 "id":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                 "type":4,
                 "propertyName":"addresses[0].state",
                 "width":[  
                    2,
                    2,
                    6
                 ],
                 "friendlyName":"State",
                 "description":null,
                 "$type":"MyApp.Infrastructure.Core.Models.UI.Controls.OptionsControl, MyApp.Infrastructure.Core"
              }
```

However, when I try to deserialize the Page (which contains the base Controls and OptionsControls), all controls are deserialized into the base Control and the `options` property (which includes the list of States, above) is ignored.

This is how I try to deserialize (and update) the Page object I receive via a WebAPI service:

```
    [HttpPut]
    [ActionName("UpdatePage")]
    public async Task<CommandResult> UpdatePageAsync([FromBody]Object page)
    {
        try
        {
            // Deserialize the page into the correct object
            // When I Debug.WriteLine the page.ToString(), the page still has the $type property at this point (before it is deserialized).
            var dsPage = return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Page>(page.ToString(), new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
            });

            // The dsPage passed in here does not have any OptionsControls.
            // At this point, they have all been deserialized into the base Control, unfortunately.
            return await _uiCommandFacade.UpdatePageAsync(dsPage, msg);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new CommandResult()
            {
                ErrorType = ErrorType.ControllerError,
                DeveloperMessage = $"Unable to update page",
                Exception = ex
            };
        }
    }
```

As you can see, I am using TypeNameHandling.All (as described in the docs and mentioned many times on SO) for the deserialization (just as I am during the serialization, which is what generates the `$type` property in the JSON). However, when I deserialize the Page object, any `OptionsControl`s in the Page object are deserialized into regular base `Control`s, so the `Options` property is ignored (and thus my list of States is not updated / thrown away).

How do I get Json.Net to properly deserialize my Controls and its derivatives?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8513042/json-net-serialize-deserialize-derived-types

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the problem might be due to the fact that the `$type` metadata property is not the first property in the JSON for your control.  Normally, Json.Net needs this property to be first in order to recognize it.  Try adding

```
MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.ReadAhead
```

to your settings when deserializing.  That should allow Json.Net to find the `$type` property later in the JSON.

Comment: Yes, after lots of hours this was also the solution for me. However, I first had to figure out *where* to set the value. Your answer combined with this one was my rescue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13274791/3812472

Answer (score 0):

I think you should setup your configuration in your web-api startup class.

Try in the startup.cs file something like

```
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Clear(); // or remove just the json one 

        var jsonformatter = new System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter()
        {
            SerializerSettings = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings()
            {
                // all your configurations
                TypeNameHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.TypeNameHandling.All
            }
        };

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Add(jsonformatter);
```

I think you are losing the informations because you get a deserialized Object item (page) in the method, then you serialize it again by calling the page.tostring() method, and then you deserialize it again with your serializer properties.