# Json.Net not saving $type information

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

When I serialize my `Page` object, Json.Net is not adding the $type property to my Controls (which are in an `IList`) when it serializes them. I have tried adding the following code to my class constructor and to my WebAPI Startup, but Json.Net is still not adding the $type information to the `Control` it serializes.

```
        JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All,
            MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.ReadAhead
        };
```

For testing purposes, I added the `$type` property to the Control myself in the JSON code, and Json.Net was able to *deserialize* the object correctly, but it is still not serializing correctly. Here's how my classes are setup.

```
public class Page {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }
    public IList<Control> Controls { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the Control class:

```
public class Control : ControlBase
{
    public override Enums.CsControlType CsControlType { get { return Enums.CsControlType.Base; } }
}
```

And here is the ControlBase abstract class:

```
public abstract class ControlBase
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Enums.CsControlType CsControlType { get; }

    public Enums.ControlType Type { get; set; }

    public string PropertyName { get; set; }

    public IList<int> Width { get; set; }

    public string FriendlyName { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the OptionsControl which is derived from Control:

```
public class OptionsControl : Control
{
    public override Enums.CsControlType CsControlType { get { return Enums.CsControlType.OptionsControl; } }

    public IDictionary<string, string> Options;
}
```

And this is how the JSON comes out:

```
"Pages": [
    {
      "Id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "CustomerId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "Controls": [
        {
          "Options": {
            "TN": "TN"
          },
          "CsControlType": 4,
          "Id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
          "Type": 4,
          "PropertyName": "addresses[0].state",
          "Width": [
            2,
            2,
            6
          ],
          "FriendlyName": "State",
          "Description": null
        }
      ]
    }
]
```

As you can see, Json.Net did not add the `$type` property to the JSON object. The problem is that sometimes I need Json.Net to give me a base `Control` object but sometimes I need it to give me an instance of the `OptionsControl` object (which inherits from `Control`). Why is Json.Net not adding the $type property to my Controls?

Comment: I might be confused, `"Type": 4,` differs from what you call `$type` how and where is that `$type` that you reference?  Can you add the "desired" output to make it more obvious?  I might just be not looking at the same thing...

Comment: Your code works fine for standalone serialization, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/gKetpA.  Therefore you must be using some framework such as web api to serialize.  What framework are you using?  For instance for MVC 4 Web API see [How to set custom JsonSerializerSettings for Json.NET in MVC 4 Web API?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13274625/3744182). Alternatively you could add `[JsonProperty(ItemTypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto)]` to your list property.

Comment: @dbc I am using .NET Core WebAPI. My question has been updated with that code. I tried adding `[JsonProperty(ItemTypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto)]` to the List and I got the `$type` for the Generic List, but not for the Controls within the List.

Comment: 1) It looks like you're using the setting during *deserialization*.  That's not going to help.  Suggest providing a full [mcve].  2) Is `[JsonProperty(ItemTypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All)] public IList<Control> Controls { get; set; }` what you want?  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/zCLbeF

Comment: @dbc You were right. This code `[JsonProperty(ItemTypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All)] public IList<Control> Controls { get; set; }` resolved the issue. Post your answer and I will accept it.

Comment: My problem was I tried to use `TypeNameHandling =` on the List instead of `ItemTypeNameHandling =`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than modifying the global settings used by your framework, you can add [`[JsonProperty(ItemTypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All)]`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute_ItemTypeNameHandling.htm) to your `public IList<Control> Controls { get; set; }` property to force type information to be emitted for each item in the list:

```
public class Page
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(ItemTypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All)]
    public IList<Control> Controls { get; set; }
}
```

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zCLbeF).

You might consider sanitizing the type information using a custom serialization binder for reasons explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39565954/3744182).