# EF: How to read complex object from API POST?

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have the following classes:

```
public partial class ReservationVersion
{
    public ReservationVersion()
    {
        this.Reservations = new HashSet<Reservation>();
        this.ReservationItems = new HashSet<ReservationItem>();
    }

    public int ReservationVersionID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ReservationID { get; set; }
    public string GUID { get; set; }
    public string StartDate { get; set; }
    public string StartTime { get; set; }
    public string Duration { get; set; }    

    public virtual ICollection<Reservation> Reservations { get; set; }
    public virtual Reservation Reservation { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ReservationItem> ReservationItems { get; set; }

}


public abstract partial class ReservationItem
{
    public ReservationItem()
    {
    }

    public int ReservationItemID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ReservationVersionID { get; set; }
    public string GUID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ParentID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> NeedsConfirmation { get; set; }
    public string ReservationSummary { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ObjectStateID { get; set; }
    public string StartDate { get; set; }
    public string StartTime { get; set; }
    public string Duration { get; set; }

    public virtual ReservationVersion ReservationVersion { get; set; }
}

public abstract partial class Appointment : ReservationItem
{
    public Appointment()
    {
    }

    public string AppointmentDescription { get; set; }
}

public partial class AppointedActivity : Appointment
{
    public Nullable<int> AppointedActivityID { get; set; }

    public virtual Activity Activity { get; set; }
}

public partial class AppointedDevice : Appointment
{
    public Nullable<int> AppointedDeviceID { get; set; }

    public virtual Device Device { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using Entity Framework and I'm having trouble understanding why I can't correctly parse a complex object from a JSON post.

Here's the JSON being sent (which is a valid `ReservationVersion`):

```
{
    "ObjectStateID": 1,
    "StartDate": "2017-10-31",
    //Other props
    "ReservationItems": [
      {
        "ReservationSummary": "Act",
        "AppointedActivityID": 95874,
        "AppointmentDescription": "ACT"
      },
      {
        "ReservationSummary": "Device",
        "AppointedDeviceID": 99040,
        "AppointmentDescription": "DEV"
      }
    ]
}
```

I can correctly read the `ReservationVersion` but the collection of `ReservationItems` is empty every time.

My guess is that there's a problem with `ReservationItems` being an abstract class and the items I'm sending should correspond to `AppointedSomething`, which inherits from `Appointment`, which inherits from `ReservationItems`

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: You are correct in your last paragraph. What serializer are you using? Maybe you can add 'hints' to the serializer on which derived types to use for reservationItems.

Comment: How would I do that? The thing is I actually need different types of `ReservationItems`. There could be an `AppointedDevice` and an `AppointedActivity` in the same Enumerable

Comment: Well, if you are in control of the json data and using JSON.Net library, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348215/how-to-deserialize-json-into-ienumerablebasetype-with-newtonsoft-json-net) looks like it may offer a solution. If not, sorry for distracting you from your true purpose!

Comment: The serialization happens on the controller: `public ReservationVersion Post([FromBody]ReservationVersion item)` Do I have control over that?

Comment: Looks like it - see [How to set custom JsonSerializerSettings for Json.NET in MVC 4 Web API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13274625/how-to-set-custom-jsonserializersettings-for-json-net-in-mvc-4-web-api). By the way - is this a WebAPI project? If so, it might be worth adding that tag to your question.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that out