# C# ASP.NET Error responses do not use GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters settings

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am using

- .NET Framework 4.6.1
- Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi 5.2.4
- ASP.NET uses Newtonsoft.Json 11.0.2

In `Global.asax` I specify that I want to use the SnakeCaseNamingStrategy for my JSON serialization:

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        ...

        var formatters = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters;

        // Remove the xmlformatter
        formatters.Remove(formatters.XmlFormatter);

        // Ignore reference loops
        formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling
            = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;

        // Use snake_case
        formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver()
        {
            NamingStrategy = new SnakeCaseNamingStrategy()
        };
    }
}
```

This works great when returning `OK` and most other success indicating status codes (200-300):

```
[HttpGet, Route("api/Test")]
public IHttpActionResult Test()
{
    return Ok(new { Message = "Hello World!" });
}
```

Returns:

```
{
    "message": "Hello World!"
}
```

But, when returning any error code or exception, ASP.NET seems to ignore any formatter settings:

```
[HttpGet, Route("api/Test")]
public IHttpActionResult Test()
{
    return BadRequest("Hello World!");
}
```

Returns:

```
{
    "Message": "Hello World!" // 'Message' is not snake_case
}
```

And

```
[HttpGet, Route("api/Test")]
public IHttpActionResult Test()
{
    var runtimeErroredArray = new int [2];
    runtimeErroredArray[2] = 5; // runtime error
    return Ok();
}
```

Returns:

```
{
    "Message": "An error has occurred.",
    "ExceptionMessage": "Index was outside the bounds of the array.", // Should be 'exception_message'
    "ExceptionType": "System.IndexOutOfRangeException", // "System.IndexOutOfRangeException" can stay the same obviously, but 'ExceptionType' should be 'exception_type'
    "StackTrace": "---"
}
```

I don't understand why this happens, but I would mainly like to know how to solve it.

**The question:**

Is there a way I can force exception messages and error code messages follow the `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver` I set in `Global.asax` (using `SnakeCaseNamingStrategy`)?

**EDIT:**

I have tried setting `JsonConvert.DefaultSettings` in `Global.asax`, but that seemed to be ignored, even when returning an `Ok` response now.

New code in `Global.asax`:

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        ...

        // Overwrite the default settings
        JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings()
        {
            // Ignore reference loops
            ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
            // Use snake_case
            ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver()
            {
                NamingStrategy = new SnakeCaseNamingStrategy()
            }
        };
    }
}
```

`return Ok(new { Message = "Hello World!" });` (like in the first example) in action `Test` now returns:

```
{
    "Message": "Hello World!"
}
```

`JsonConvert.DefaultSettings` Seems to be ignored completely by ASP.NET.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18832929/558486

Comment: @RuiJarimba Thanks for the response. None of the answers on that question seemed to work unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After quite some research I pinpointed some differences in the ASP.NET Mvc source code (see https://github.com/aspnet and https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC) regarding returning success codes and failure codes.

These differences all had one crucial similarity which pointed me to the solution of this problem.

### Explanation

In ASP.NET Mvc there are 2 extension methods for creating `HttpResponseMessage`'s

- [`CreateErrorResponse`](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http/HttpRequestMessageExtensions.cs#LC455)
- [`CreateResponse`](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http/HttpRequestMessageExtensions.cs#LC532)

After looking at both methods I didn't think I saw anything that could cause returning error codes or throwing exceptions serialize incorrectly. But after looking at [`BadRequestErrorMessageResult`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/a67d9363e22be8ef63a1a62539991e1da3a6e30e/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim/BadRequestErrorMessageResult.cs), I found out `CreateErrorResponse` and `BadRequestErrorMessageResult` use the [***`HttpError`***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.http.httperror?view=aspnetcore-2.1) class to pass their information to the serializer.

Due to `HttpError` extending `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,object>` the serializer did not serialize the `HttpError` with the settings I specified, because Dictioneries are treated differently during serialization.

**TL;DR**

Whenever ASP.NET Mvc returns an error; it will use the [***`HttpError`***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.http.httperror?view=aspnetcore-2.1) class, which is a `Dictionary<string, object>`. Dictionaries have separate settings for serialization.

### The Answer

You have to specify you want to parse Dictionary keys in your serialization settings:

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        // ...

        var formatters = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters;

        // Remove the xmlformatter
        formatters.Remove(formatters.XmlFormatter);

        // Ignore reference loops
        formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling
            = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;

        // Use snake_case
        formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver()
        {
            NamingStrategy = new SnakeCaseNamingStrategy()
            {
                ProcessDictionaryKeys = true // <--- Use SnakeCaseNamingStrategy for Dictionaries (So HttpError's)
            }
        };
    }
}
```