# ef6 linq method returning $ref for nested entries in query

Tags: linq, entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2

my linq method system from EF6 is returning $ref when I monitor results in fiddler.  If I watch the local window in my webapi everything is populated correctly, but not in the actual results that are returned.  It only affects the nested entries.  anyone know what I am doing wrong?  (I created models from database in EF6)

```
            var student = dbEF.Accounts
                        .Where(x => x.AccountNumber == acctNum)
                        .Select(x => new DTOCrmDetails()
                        {
                            AccountNumber = x.AccountNumber,

                            CommissionId = x.CommissionId,
                            Commission = x.Commission,

                            ManagerID = x.ManagerID,
                            ManagerName = x.Manager.ManagerName,
                            Manager = x.Manager,

                            Employees = x.Manager.Employees,

                            WireInstructionsUSD = x.Manager.WireInstructionsUSDs

                        //Mapping_ManagersExecutingBrokers = x.Manager.Mapping_ManagersExecutingBrokers

                    }).FirstOrDefault();

        return student;
```

these are my settings.

```
var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter; json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects; config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter); config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented; config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
```

Comment: What do the app's serializer settings look like?

Comment: how do I check that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13274625/861716

Comment: Please edit your question instead of adding code in comments. Anyway, the settings [explain your finding](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PreserveReferencesHandlingObject.htm).

Comment: i commented out the line where is preserveReferencesHandling.Objects and now I get an error in fiddler... self referencing loop detered for 'manager'

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable your lazy loading in the entity framework dbcontext.

something like this way:

```
dbEF.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

Comment: I added [JsonIgnore] to the virtual attributes that are not coming up and it is working.  Any idea what this does and why it is working now?